# Drupal hook menu and node form

Tags: nodes, routes, forms

I have a content type **leg** and this `hook_menu` :

```
$items['leg'] = array(
    'title' => t('Choose Leg'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access arguments' => array('create leg content'),
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_leg_select_form'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => 0,
);

$items['leg/select'] = array(
    'title' => t('Choose an existing leg'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access arguments' => array('create leg content'),      
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_leg_select_form'),
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 1,
);  

$items['leg/add'] = array(
    'title' => t('Create a new leg'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access arguments' => array('create leg content'),      
    'page arguments' => array('leg_node_form'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 2,
);  
return $items;
```

Here is the code snippet from `mymodule_leg_select_form()` which is called as MENU DEFAULT LOCAL TASK :

```
$form = array();    
$result = db_query('SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND status = :status ORDER BY title', array(':type'=>'leg', ':status'=>1));
$options = array();
foreach($result as $row){
    $options[$row->nid] = $row->title;
}
$form['leg'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Leg'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Ok'),
    '#weight' => 1,
);

return $form;
```

The node form is not rendered correctly as you can see in the screen shot. I have two fields - `field_from` and `field_to`. They are not rendered in the form. The menu path "leg/select" which is default local task did work and correctly rendered my custom form.

The problem only is to integrate node add form in the second tab.
How can I fix this error ?

[image]

Comment: Did you clear the cache? This look like old stuff is still hanging around.

Comment: Yes, I did clear the cache, but still see the errors.

Comment: Post the leg_node_form function. Are all of these in the same .module file?

Comment: I think there is no `leg_node_form` function. It is just a form id to the drupal node form infrastructure in the form of `{contenttype}_node_form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your `hook_menu` implementation, but your function `leg_node_form`. That function probably calles `node_form`, which is in file `modules/node/node.pages.inc` you have to include that file manually using [`module_load_include`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_load_include).

Comment: After I added this : function mymodule_init(){ module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); }. I got this error : Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\field\field.attach.inc on line 197

Comment: I see this issue at drupal.org/node/947748, but they are saying about media module and drupal beta verson. I have no media module and my drupal is 7.7.

Comment: A better place to include `node.pages.inc` would be the function that calls `node_form` (I suspect this is `mymodule_leg_select_form`). Also, if the error is in function `mymodule_leg_select_form`, show us this function.

Comment: I updated my original post with the code for `mymodule_leg_select_form`, but it is called by menu default local task. I got the error only when I navigate to the second tab. I tried to add 'file' and 'file path' to `node.pages.inc` in the menu registration "leg/add". But still see the error : `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in path\to\site\modules\field\field.attach.inc on line 197`. I have two fields for the content type leg - field_from and field_to and hided title and body field.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I suspect the error is in `leg_node_form`.

Comment: Including node.pages.inc resolves my original issue, but then I got another error of the `field` module . I posted it as another question here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20084/d7-field-module-error-when-calls-drupal-get-from